# jQuery mobile website desktop preview

Tags: jquery-mobile, html, iframe, smartphone

I have a jQuery mobile website built and working. However I need customers to have a live preview of the mobile website so I have built a page which has a div, image of phone inside the div and then an iframe is positioned nicely within the div. The mobile site looks fine scaling wise on a smartphone and not too bad on a normal desktop pc I have the following meta tag set:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
```

However when viewing the mobile site via the iframe its scalled too big, does anyone know of a good way to resolve this or is it not possible?

Comment: Have you find a solution about your problem? I am also looking for a workaround

Comment: I just made the iframe slightly bigger in width and it seemed to make it a lot better.